# XML creation using DOM and MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, dom

I am trying to create a XML document from information extracted from a mysql table. I am using a tutorial to accomplish this

http://www.tonymarston.net/php-mysql/dom.html#a5

what I want to do is to create each element separately, instead of creating them all at once as shown in the tutorial. In order to do that I am trying to place the specific field name into the foreach loop below, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
foreach ($row as where fieldname should go  => $row['artistname'])
  {
  $artval = $doc->createTextNode($row['artistname']);
  $artval = $chil->appendChild($val);
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`mysql_fetch_assoc`](http://fr.php.net/mysql_fetch_assoc) will fetch the data of a whole row, and return an array, indexed by fields names.

Which means that, after using this line :

```
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($resouter);
```

The `$row` variable will be an array containing several items ; one for each column returned by the SQL query.

To see that, you can use something like :

```
var_dump($row);
```

Which will dump to the standard output the content of the `$row` variable -- which could help you figure out what it contains.

Then, if you just want to access one field of this array, no need fdor a loop : `$row` being an [associative array][2], you can use syntax such as `$row['NAME OF THE FIELD']` to access each field.